# Nodejs Parsing nested json array

Tags: javascript, node.js

this is simple code which i want to parse `values` json array and print data from that,

```
var data = {
    "mobileNumber": "3",
    "userContacts": {
        "values": [{
            "nameValuePairs": {
                "contactName": "aaaaa",
                "contactPhone": "111111"
            }
        }, {
            "nameValuePairs": {
                "contactName": "bbbbb",
                "contactPhone": "222222"
            }
        }]
    }
};

var jsonArray = JSON.parse(data.userContacts.values);

for (var i=0; i<jsonArray['values'].length; i++){

    //print contactName and contactPhone from nameValuePairs

}
```

i created [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/o9nn262b/) on `jsFiddle` to test that

Comment: And is something not working?

Comment: @code11 no my code doesn't work and i get error

Comment: Ok, what error do you get? Include it please as part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or just :

```
data.userContacts.values.forEach(x => {
  console.log(x.nameValuePairs.contactName, x.nameValuePairs.contactPhone);
});
// aaaaa 111111
// bbbbb 222222
```

Comment: its very useful for me, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to use `JSON.parse`. You already have a JSON.

You can just loop over what you need.

```
for (var i=0; i<data.userContacts.values.length; i++){
    console.log(data.userContacts.values[i].nameValuePairs.contactName,
                data.userContacts.values[i].nameValuePairs.contactPhone)
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ffv4grk7/

Also, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript) for more info on how `JSON.parse` works.

Comment: And you were actually having a loop over the array `data.userContacts.values.values`, which does not exist.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code you will get name and email

```
 for(i in data.userContacts.values) {
   x+=data.userContacts.values[i].nameValuePairs.contactName+"<BR>";
   x+=data.userContacts.values[i].nameValuePairs.contactPhone+"<BR>"; }
   document.getElementById("r").innerHTML = x;
```